# Trying to make if, else on azure using variables

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

So i azure have the variables section on the pipelines, and i had lots of .yml on the same repository, which is a problem, i wanted to make a pipeline that i can define the variable on azure and it changes the template, for example on this one:
[The variable on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET88D.png)

```
variables:
  buildpipe: ''

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: the-name/template-pipelines

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.buildpipe, 'apk') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines.yml@templates
  ${{ elif eq(variables.buildpipe, 'exe') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines-exe.yml@templates
```

I tried to create the variable buildpipe on the azure pipeline to make it change the template file, i was trying with just two of it for a long time but i didn't get it to work, i wanted to have 3 accepted variables, the apk, exe and web, but i can't get it to work with even those two, every time i try something i get a different error, is there a solution or workaround this?
The error at the moment is:

Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 13, Col: 3): Unexpected symbol: 'eq'. Located at position 6 within expression: elif eq(variables.buildpipe, 'exe'). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

I've never asked anything on this website before so i apologize if i did something wrong typing about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems here.
First of all you misspelled `elseif`. Also that line must be started from dash, in same way as `if` line.
Next thing here is that you need to pay attention what variables do you use in that conditions: in compile-time expressions you can use [only statically defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops). It will work if you will hardcode your value into yaml or will keep **only** pipeline variable (as on your screenshot). Currently pipeline variable value is overwritten by value in yaml.

This works for me:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: the-name/template-pipelines
      
steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.buildpipe, 'apk') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines.yml@templates
- ${{ elseif eq(variables.buildpipe, 'exe') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines-exe.yml@templates
```

But I would suggest you to try parameter here instead of variable. It will be easier to change value and harder to make mistake. In your case it will looks like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: buildpipe
    type: string
    default: apk
    values:
      - apk
      - exe
      - web

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: the-name/template-pipelines

steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.buildpipe, 'apk') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines.yml@templates
- ${{ elseif eq(parameters.buildpipe, 'exe') }}:
  - template: azure-pipelines-exe.yml@templates
```

And the best part is that pipeline run window will looks like this:
[image]